# Async Recognition returns 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED status

Tags: google-speech-api

I want to recognize some audio files, so I uploaded them to a Storage Bucket. Those audio files are ~45 min long; the async recognition is mandatory.

I have a pair of audio files already recognized, but the service [speech.asyncrecognize](https://cloud.google.com/speech/reference/rest/v1beta1/speech/asyncrecognize) is returning me a 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED status since a few hours ago.

My GCP project has the Google Cloud Speech API enabled and the billing info set. The entire quota for the API is available, and I have only 10 audio files to recognize, so it is not a volume problem.

So, why am I getting this 429 status? I know this API is beta, but is weird it suddenly stopped working.

I am consuming this API via REST with Python. My code looks something like this:

```python
import json
import requests

headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer my-token",
    "Content-Type": "application/json"
}

data = json.dumps({
    "config": {
        "encoding": "LINEAR16",
        "languageCode": "en-US",
        "sampleRate": 16000
    },
    "audio": {
        "uri": "gs://my-bucket/my-audio.wav"
    }
})

r = requests.post(
    "https://speech.googleapis.com/v1beta1/speech:asyncrecognize",
    headers=headers,
    data=data
)

print r.text
```

And it returns:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": 429,
        "message": "Quota exceeded.",
        "status": "RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED"
    }
}
```

It worked twice, but now fails. Anyone with the same problem?

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: Yes @PRANSHUMIDHA. It was a size problem, or specifically a duration one. Check the [usage limits](https://cloud.google.com/speech/limits), maybe you're out of quota in any of them. Check also [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cloud-speech-discuss/resource_exhausted/cloud-speech-discuss/Oa6Brw2nIek/WQwyslg4BwAJ) of the official Speech API Google Group :-)